# How can i remove unwanted spaces from the string using enumerate function and for loop

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop, if-statement, enumerate

**i have this code but it is not working.. i don't know what's wrong in this code**

```
djtext = "g o d  i s   gre at"
analyzed = ""
for index, char in enumerate(djtext):
    if not(djtext[index] == " " and djtext[index+1]==" "):
      analyzed = analyzed + char
print(analyzed)
```

*I want the output like this*

> god is great

*But it gave me this output*

> g o d i s gre at

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result you want by using `split` to split the string on two spaces and then `join` the parts again with the spaces removed

```
' '.join(word.replace(' ', '') for word in djtext.split('  ') if word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this alternative solution using regular expressions:

```
import re
djtext = "g o d  i s   gre at"
analyzed = re.sub(r' (.)', lambda x: x.group(1), djtext)
print(analyzed)
```

This matches a space followed by *any character*, and replaces all such sequences with just the *character* that was matched.

This gives the desired output:

> god is great

If you want to stick with your original approach, then you need to add an extra condition to make it work. Your original code covers one cases (*reducing* multiple spaces) but misses the other cases (*removing* the unnecessary spaces).

The following version is the correct version of your code. It adds the condition `char == " " and djtext[index - 1] != " "`, which just checks that if the current character is a space, the character before it is not also a space. In such a case, you wouldn't want to keep the space.

```
djtext = "g o d  i s   gre at"
analyzed = ""
for index, char in enumerate(djtext):
    if not((char == " " and djtext[index + 1] == " ") or (char == " " and djtext[index - 1] != " ")):
        analyzed += char
print(analyzed)
```

Side note: for readability, I've switched `djtext[index]` to `char` and `analyzed = analyzed + char` to `analyzed += char`.

Comment: But i think my solution is having some mistake.. can you please point out that mistake so that i know why my solution is not working..

Comment: I want to know what i am doing wrong in this way of solving the problem...

Comment: @saurav I've updated the answer to include the problem with your original version + a corrected version